# Problem with 9 patch image as background

Tags: android, listview, nine-patch

I have a list view structure, with Relative layout that uses
alternating background images for odd/even elements. I'm trying to set
the background drawable dynamically by calculating the position. It
worked fine with the normal bitmap. But when I tried to use the
ninepatch image it breaks the UI, all the elements get distorted. What
am I doing wrong? Could it be how the ninepatch image is created or is
there a different way to use a ninepatch image compared to a normal
bitmap.

My List View XML goes like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/id01"
       android:background="@drawable/my_9patch_bg_image">
       <ImageView  />
       <RelativeLayout>
         <ImageView  />
          <TextView  />
          <TextView  />
       </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

May be the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904852/android-layout-broken-with-9-patch-background) might work for my problem. It's exact though I have to try it.

Comment: May be you have badly-formated 9-patch?

Comment: I have tried different variations of the 9 patch image all of which give the preview I desired. But the content inside my first RelativeLayout is gone when that particular list view activity is up. Worked fine with normal bitmap image though.

Comment: A screenshot of what's happening, an image of what you want to happen and the 9 patch might help people determine what the problem is.

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904852/android-layout-broken-with-9-patch-background?lq=1


is same problem with code exapmle :)

Answer (score 33):

Since nobody answered you for a year now...
I had the same issue you need to setpadding of zero (even if you don't need it).

Good luck.

Comment: Didn't work for me, the 9 patch still shows stretched.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nine patch in the same way you use a normal drawable. I assume you have a problem with the 9 patch itself. In the /tools directory of your android sdk you have the draw 9 patch tool. It will help you to correct your 9 patch drawable and to preview it for different sizes of your view.

Comment: I tried fixing the image with the draw9patch tool. Tried different variations but didn't get it to work. What should be the ideal way to draw if the image is supposed to scale in (+x,-y) direction?

Answer (score 0):

select all sides except corners as the stretching edges

Answer (score 0):

you can use this xml as background to show as cardview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        <solid android:color="#e2e2e2" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:bottom="2dp">
    <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>
```