# Adding a background image to RelativeLayout hide all others elements

Tags: android, background, android-edittext, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a simple XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/login_background">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="218dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:textColor="@color/surtimax_gris_texto"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:hint="@string/login_edittext_user_text"
            android:textColorHint="@color/surtimax_gris_texto" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:background="@drawable/login_edittext_background"
            android:textColor="@color/surtimax_gris_texto"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:hint="@string/login_edittext_pass_text"
            android:textColorHint="@color/surtimax_gris_texto" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is: neither in emulator or real device is showing LinearLayout and EditText **when** RelativeLayout has a background.
If I just remove the background everything works fine... it's weird.
Not error logs about app.

minSdkVersion 17
targetSdkVersion 22

**UPDATED**
Its working with normal background image (non 9patch). So the problem is about background 9patch image.

**UPDATED 2**
There is a lot of questions/answers about using 9patch in background in SO, but because the problem I faced was applying the background I started to looking in google for "background image problems". Of course none of the result in google throw me any useful answer. When Kai gave me and advice about the problem I easily found the problem. So I'm not going to close the question because it can help to someone to go through.

Comment: Is login_background a 9patch, and does the same thing happen if you change the background to other drawables?

Comment: Yeah, login_background is a 9patch, but I have not tried with other drawables. I will try tomorrow.

Comment: @peter it's not happening with a normal background image. Do you know what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Ok I just fixed my google search to 9patch background image problem and I got some questions/answers that gave me and advice of what was going on: I had not defined "content area" in 9patch image. The links are: [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904852/android-layout-broken-with-9-patch-background) [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040720/problem-with-9-patch-image-as-background). Because you were the one that put me in the right way to find the answer, you are welcome to post the answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks, do note that while set padding works, in normal situations it's better to provide both the stretch definition and the drawable definition

Comment: Yeah, I did the second one (provide stretch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your background is set with a 9patch image that doesn't define both the stretch area (left and top corners) and the drawable area (right and bottom corners).

The solution is either modify 9patch image to include the necessary information, or set padding to 0 (`android:padding="0dip"` in XML or `setPadding(0)` in code).