# Why nine-patch image in RelativeLayour hides all inner elements?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, nine-patch

When I set 9.PNG image as `RelativeLayout`'s background, all elements inside it gets shrunken to the middle. Here is the XML and the snapshot.

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        >
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Just a simple white text which does not show up"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: nine-patch background]

If I change background to a color or a normal image, I get the text.

```
android:background="@drawable/bg2" //normal image
```

[image: normal-image background]

Can anyone explain why is this happening?

Comment: A clear answer of your problem is provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904852/android-layout-broken-with-9-patch-background

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you define the content area of your nine-patch? Because it looks like the content area is the little pixel in the middle.

The content area is defined by the bottom and right sides of your nine patch. You can for example make it as big as your patch.