# My textview keeps getting hidden behind it's parent layout background

Tags: android, background, textview

http://oi41.tinypic.com/2z6tuh5.jpg

In this picture, the orange thing is supposed to be the letter A, but it constantly gets cut-off by the background of the parent layout. Anyone have any idea what might be causing this, and how to fix it. I tried experimenting with different layouts and stuff, but it always gets cut off.

And BTW it's not padding, I checked.

Here's the code for the activity `

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#16467A"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/liniar"
        android:layout_width="205dp"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_ok"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:background="@drawable/kvadrat"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="204dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/graph1"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
                android:background="#00a313"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/graph2"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="140dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/graph1"
                    android:background="#00a313"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/graph2"
                    android:background="#00a313"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/graph4"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
                    android:background="#00a313"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="4"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20dip" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="204dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:text="A"
                    android:textColor="#DCA601"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="normal" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_ok"
        android:layout_width="204dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/liniar"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/kvadrat"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="ОК"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>`
```

And here's the kvadrat.9.png which is used for the background of one of the components.
http://oi42.tinypic.com/rssc3p.jpg

It looks all fine in the XML editor, but when I actually compile it in Virtual machine, the textview becomes half-hidden.

EDIT: Nevermind, this post [Why nine-patch image in RelativeLayour hides all inner elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105390/why-nine-patch-image-in-relativelayour-hides-all-inner-elements) helped me find the mistake. I hadn't configured my 9patch file correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to solve this if you put the code of your layout design here... Which exactly is the background of the parent layout?