# Creating Android background images

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to manage background images for android applications?

I have my backgrounds looking pretty sweet in my app, however, when ported to another device they are stretched to fit and look awefull.

So my question is how do i specify my background image size in dp to account for the ever changing range of devices??

any help would be great - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

use 9patch images . this will allow you to bound background image according to foreground contents . see 9patch drawable docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) .

Comment: okay, i have gone through the tut and im able to create images which need a little tweaking but is pretty much what i want. However, since using the new .p.png file all my buttons have dissapeared!!

Comment: have found the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904852/android-layout-broken-with-9-patch-background by adding this line to the layout android:padding="0dip"

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look on [How to support Multiple screen devices in android](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

You may have to create different layouts and also different drawable folders to support different resolutions and different size of screen.