# Layout: background picture stretched

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have difficulties with my layout.

As my first dev project, I'm trying to make a simple chronometer.
I want to have a picture of a chronometer in the background and the start and stop button
at the bottom of the application, side by side and filling the width of the screen.

Here is my best shot, but I'm not satisfied.

All widgets are placed properly but ...
My background is streched and my buttons seem vertically compressed, even the text at the bottom is a bit cropped.

I found that if I change these lines

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

by

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

The background is ok, the buttons too .. but all widgets are placed in the center of the Activity.

How can I fix this ?

By the way if I want to have my buttons side by side, did I choose the better solution ?

Thanks for your help !
Charles.

... and now my xml ....

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context=".Chronosv1" >

<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_weight="2" >

<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/chronometer1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="START" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="STOP" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried relativeLayout.
I don't know how to have two buttons of the same size without using a padding, I don't think it's a good idea if you want your app to run on different screens.

Anyway I come up with this, but I still have my streched image and my buttons don't have the same size.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context=".Chronosv1" >

<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/chronometer1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Start" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
    android:text="Stop" />
```

Comment: 1) Most likely, you'll need something more advanced than `LinearLayout`; (2) What is your `Chronometer` component?

Comment: Chronmeter is an android widget
android.widget.Chronometer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

First problem: my 9 patch image hid my other component.

Solution: add **android:padding="0dip"** in your linearlayout ... here the subject that gave me my  answer ([Android layout broken with 9-patch background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904852/android-layout-broken-with-9-patch-background))

Second problem: why my picture was streched whereas I designed it at the exact size of the screen. This one was a silly question ... it was because of the action bar and the other bar above (with battery level and other stuff).

To get rid of theses bars (included in the theme) use a different version of the Theme in the manifest.

I choose: Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen.

Problems solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try RelativeLayout ;) I think this is much easier to handle than a LinearLayout. Maybe you can upload a picture how it looks like and I will give you a relativelayout solution ;)

Comment: I have some difficulties with this layer, I found how to put the buttons side by side, but not how to fill all the width of the screen.

I enclosed a snapshot of my screen.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this out? Should work IMO.
It is a better/fool-proof way to obtain your layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context=".Chronosv1" >


<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/layout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="2"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:text="Start" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:text="Stop" />
</LinearLayout>
<Chronometer
android:id="@+id/chronometer1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_above="@+id/layout1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: For the buttons it's ok, but the background is still steched.

Comment: I noticed that the top title bar (the one with the name of the app) has an effect on the background picture ... I don't understand why but my 320x240 picture is not displayed properly because of it.

I tried to convert my picture to a 9 patch image. Now in Eclipse/Graphical Layout everything is ok but on my AVD and on my phone the other components are not anymore displayed ... grrrrrr.